# Apex charts - Column width option does not work

Tags: apexcharts

We use a stacked bar chart from Apexcharts library with the following setting:

```
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    columnWidth: '90%',
  }
}
```

Expected behavior: Each stacked bar will take 90% of the available width.

In fact, the actual with of bars may vary as about 40% to 90% of the available width. Sometimes it can be different with exactly the same data.

[image]

[image]

We tried to use different values for `columnWidth` (both in `%` and `px`)

Comment: I do not reproduce this problem. What is your version of ApexCharts? Do you use a framework?

Comment: @Badacadabra I think the problem was caused by a timestamp added at the end of the series. Thank you anyway